# NgTagsInput add on enter adds from autocomplete and not what is typed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-tags-input

I have a tags input field like this:

```
    <tags-input class="bootstrap"
            ng-model="tags"
            placeholder="Voeg een tag toe"
            replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
            add-from-autocomplete-only="false">
    <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"
                 min-length="0"
                 debounce-delay="0"
                 load-on-focus="true"
                 load-on-empty="true"
                 selectFirstMatch="false"
                 max-results="10"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
```

This is the loadTags:

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return [
        'Productie',
        'Gevelreclame',
        'Studio',
        'Freesletters',
        'Online',
        'Peter',
        'Gerroy',
        'Robert'
    ];
};
```

But when I type to add a tag, and I press enter to add it it adds the selected one from the autocomplete and not the value that I typed. But when I click out of the input, it adds the tag with the value I typed. But I want this to work with a enter aswell. I cant get this figured out.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the tagsinput I needed to add the attribute: add-from-autocomplete-only="false"
and on the autocomplete I needed to add the attribute: select-first-match="false".

This fixed it for me